# $.browser.safari and $.browser.webkit shows undefined in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Is it a `jQuery 1.8.0` bug or a `Chrome's` bug that `$.browser.safari` and `$.browser.webkit` throws `undefined`

[**See Example Fiddle** - JQUERY 1.8.0](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Pd3gf/)

[**See Example Fiddle** - JQUERY 1.7.2](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Pd3gf/)

**Note: I am using Chrome `21.0.1180.83 m`**

Comment: `$.browser` is deprecated and feature detection is recommended instead.

Comment: It is working in safari.. Why not working in chrome..

Comment: If someone is curious why it is deprecated here is the quote from [jQuery.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) API: *Because `$.browser` uses `navigator.userAgent` to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible. The `$.support` property is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on `$.browser`.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), `$.browser.safari` is deprecated. Also, the *entire* `$.browser` object isn't even recommended for use:

> **Description:** Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

Anyways, `$.browser.chrome` is defined for Chrome (at least for me).

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pd3gf/1/**

Why do you need to detect browsers in the first place? Just use [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) to see whether a browser supports a specific feature.

Comment: Thanks for the more clarifications.